Failed to initialize the Paparazzi
I tried to connect Paparazzi to the project. Implemented plugin and libs:
classpath("app.cash.paparazzi:paparazzi-gradle-plugin:1.3.4")
id("app.cash.paparazzi") version "1.3.4" apply false
add("testImplementation", "app.cash.paparazzi:paparazzi:$paparazziVersion") // 1.3.4

Wrote a simple test for compose function:
class NewsContentPaparazziTest {

    @get:Rule
    val paparazzi = Paparazzi(
        deviceConfig = PIXEL_5,
        theme = "android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar"
    )

    @Test
    fun newsContentScreenshotTest() {
        paparazzi.snapshot {
            AppTheme {
                NewsContent(
                    state = sampleNewsState(),
                    dispatchIntent = {}
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

After launch I got an error:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:209)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:216)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Path.of(Path.java:147)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:69)
    at app.cash.paparazzi.EnvironmentKt.detectEnvironment(Environment.kt:87)
    at app.cash.paparazzi.Paparazzi.<init>(Paparazzi.kt:31)
    at com.example.news.ui.NewsContentPaparazziTest.<init>(NewsContentPaparazziTest.kt:14)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:250)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:260)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$2.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:112)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:40)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:52)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$2.run(TestWorker.java:176)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:113)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:65)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)

Exception happens exactly on the Paparazzi initialization. I use JAVA 21 and I thouth problem inside that, so I downgraded Java to 17 - it didn't change the problem.
This simple code shows that version is correct and avaiable:
@Test
fun addition_isCorrect() {
    println(System.getProperty("java.version")) // 17.0.11
}

So, what you think? Where is a problem?

did you apply the paparazzi plugin to your module? I can see that you have apply false (which is probably in the root build.gradle.kts), but you have to also apply it to the module. It should set up the environment for the test run.

Yes it is, but I applied it with false as in settings.kts. I removed the extra apply false and everything started working) Thanks! Please add your answer and I will accept it as correct

posted, thanks!

The issue is that you haven't applied the paparazzi gradle plugin to your module.
I can see that you have apply false for the paparazzi plugin (which is probably in the root build.gradle.kts file), but you also have to apply it to the module. It should set up the environment for the test run.
